# I'm having trouble displaying my randomly selected object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables, object

I am having trouble displaying the random object and the properties of that random object. The goal of this project is to have a list of stockItems, and when I press a button, it selects a determined number of those objects and displays them in an HTML p tag. Right now when I try to display it, it prints out as [object]. The goal is to have the properties of the selected object on different lines.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
function buildShopItems(count) {
  var shopItems = [], i, itemIndex;
  count = stockItems.length < count ? stockItems.length : count;

  function getUniqueRandomItem() { //from stock
    var item;
    while (true) {
      item = stockItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * stockItems.length)];
      if (shopItems.indexOf(item) < 0) return item;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    shopItems.push(getUniqueRandomItem());
  }
  return shopItems;
  console.log(shopItems);
}


var stockItems = [
  { item: "sword", type: "weapon", weight: "5 lbs.", cost: "10 gold" },
  { item: "hammer", type: "weapon", weight: "8 lbs.", cost: "7 gold" }
  //...
];


var shopItems = buildShopItems(1);


console.log(shopItems);

document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = shopItems.item;
document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = shopItems.type;
document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML = shopItems.weight;
document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = shopItems.cost;
```

Comment: Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately. You should already have seen the `unreachable code after return statement` warning.

Comment: Your upper `console.log(shopItems);` will never execute, as you are running a `return` before it. Also, `while(true){}` is **never** a good idea...

Comment: `shopItems` is an array. `shopItems.item` and the like do not make sense.

Comment: @Xufox What would I use to display the randomly selected object in that array?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Do you have a suggestion on something I could use besides while(true){}?

Comment: @Caseyewillis You know how to access specific elements from an array. Just do that.

Comment: `shopItems` is indeed an array. Specifically, an array comprising multiple objects. You need to add the index of the array to your `innerHTML`: you can access the cost of the first item with `shopItems[0].cost`, and the weight of the second with `shopItems[1].weight`, or better yet, loop the output for both items :)

Comment: @Xufox I don't understand. I apologize for my lack of knowledge, but I am trying here. When I try to display it, I get [Object, Object].

Comment: @ObsidianAge I could hug you! That was exactly the piece of information I was looking for. Thank you SO much for your help!

Comment: No problem ;) Though you also cannot output the second set of items with `shopItems[1]` with your current code -- I'm looking into that :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Just ran into that, haha! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. It means a ton! Do you know why it would work with [0] but not [1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with your usage of `indexOf`. You can use `indexOf` to search for an object because in javascript you can't compare object using `==` or `===` and indexOf uses `===`. Also made some syntax updates for you.

```
'use strict'

const stockItems = [
  { item: "sword", type: "weapon", weight: "5 lbs.", cost: "10 gold" },
  { item: "hammer", type: "weapon", weight: "8 lbs.", cost: "7 gold" }
];

function isEquivalent(a, b) {
    // Create arrays of property names
    const aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
    const bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

    // If number of properties is different,
    // objects are not equivalent
    if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
        const propName = aProps[i];

        // If values of same property are not equal,
        // objects are not equivalent
        if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If we made it this far, objects
    // are considered equivalent
    return true;
}

// normal indexof will not work with object because it uses strict equality
function myIndexOf(array, object) {    
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (isEquivalent(array[i], object)) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

function getUniqueRandomItem(shopItems) { //from stock
  var item;
  while (true) {
    item = stockItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * stockItems.length)];
    if (myIndexOf(shopItems, item) < 0) return item;
  }
}

function buildShopItems(count) {
  count = stockItems.length < count ? stockItems.length : count;
  const shopItems = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const item = getUniqueRandomItem(shopItems);
    shopItems.push(item);
  }

  return shopItems;
}

const shopItems = buildShopItems(1);


console.log(shopItems);
```